# Is there a shortcut for moving selected message(s) to the Junk folder in macOS Mail?

Tags: macos, mail.app

Question in the title is self explanatory.

Comment: If it's Junk, why not just delete it, or, if you have one, tell your spam filter to treat it as spam?

Comment: It's getting through my spam filter, and I want to move it to my junk folder because that increases the chances of my spam filter picking out similar messages in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the menus you can see keyboard shortcuts next to the commands. For this it is:
<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>

[image: Message Menu]

Comment: I don't see any command next to Move To Junk (it's itself is a parent menu, but selecting it works too)

Comment: what version of mail.app are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You can create one by going to settings > keyboard > shortcuts. Then find what you are saying and create or activate the shortcut